# How to perform stemming in apache spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, nlp

I am doing a simple project using K-Means clustering in apache spark and i did some preprocessing steps like tokenization, stop words remover,and hashingTF. These are performed by spark own Tokenization(),StopWordRemover() and HasingTF(). But i want to perform stemming before applying k-means clustering.I have tried some NLP libraries in openNLP. But I don't know how to implement it in spark DataFrame.
Can someone help me how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/master/spark-stemming

Comment: i am trying to add snowball stemming  in build.sbt file. But it shows error  Unresolved dependencies: master#spark-stemming_2.11;0.1.2 not found

Answer (score 4):

You can use spark stemming as mentioned by shashank from this project: https://github.com/master/spark-stemming It supports quite a lot of languages. See the list at: https://github.com/master/spark-stemming/tree/master/src/main/java/org/tartarus/snowball/ext

To add the project to your build.sbt you need to add another resolver:

```
resolvers ++= Seq("spark-stemming" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/")
```

and import dependency:

```
"master" % "spark-stemming" % "0.1.1"
```

not version 0.1.2

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying the same thing, But did not find anything regarding adding dependency to build.sbt. By the time we can figure out how to put dependency in build.sbt, One work around is you can download the jar from https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.github.master:spark-stemming_2.10/0.1.0 location and specify this jar in spark-submit --jars  or spark-shell --jars command and use its classes.

Comment: can you please tell me how to specify the jar in intellij idea?

Comment: To add the jar in IntelliJ  follow the below step --
Go to 
-- File 
-- Project Structure 
-- Then you should see Libraries on the left hand side. Click on it.
-- Click on plus(+) sign 
-- Java
-- Location of the jar file
-- Apply
-- Ok

Comment: This is for IntelliJ version 2016.3.2

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is the [Spark-NLP](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp) library from [John Snow Labs](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/).  It has both Stem and Lemma annotators, along with a large collection of other annotators, transformers and pretrained models & pipelines.  All of which work with both PySpark and Scala Spark.

The documentation is thorough, and explicitly states how to perform the installation of the library in a variety of scenarios and languages.